Was Minnie seeking revenge, or was she thwarting the demonic entities in "Late Night with the Devil"?
In the 2023 horror film Late Night with the Devil, it was revealed that Lilly, a guest on the talk show hosted by Jack Delroy (played by David Dastmalchian), is possessed by a demonic entity she calls "Mr. Wriggles." This entity, as June calls it, is a "minor deity"—a servant of a higher deity, Abraxas.
Mr. Wriggles mentions that he and Jack crossed paths before at "The Grove," an exclusive camp used by a secretive club for the rich and powerful elite, of which Jack is a member. ("We met amongst the tall trees.")
As Lilly's possession escalates, it is implied that Jack may have struck a deal with "the devil" Abraxas at The Grove—the classic "Deal with the Devil" trope. The deal may have involved sacrificing the life of his wife, Madeleine (nicknamed "Minnie"), in exchange for career success.
It is also revealed (but hinted earlier by the psychic medium Christou and other split-second appearances) that Minnie's spirit is also in the studio. At one point, her face is superimposed on Lilly's head, and at another point, she is spookily shown with her hands on Jack's shoulder.

The screencaps above depict the same scenes. The left screencap depicts the scene's initial occurrence, and the right screencap depicts the videotape playback of that same scene.
I'm not exactly sure what Minnie's ghost was trying to accomplish by spooking Jack and the audience like that. Was she seeking revenge on Jack for sacrificing her life, aiding the demonic forces in enacting their nefarious plan upon him? Or was she attempting to save her husband from the clutches of the very demonic forces he had made a deal with? Or do her actions stem from another reason?

The ending wasn't exactly parsimonious. Unless the writer or chatbot declared what they intended I think viewer interpretation is fair since there's no clear answer and it seems to me they were throwing everything in.  Personally I wish it had stuck to "the Exorcist" pastiche and left the "Rosemary's Baby" career elements out.

I hadn't planned on watching this, but mentioning The Grove now has me interested. I had heard a podcast regarding The Grove last year.

I've asked myself this question a lot since watching and it's truly one of those questions that has good arguments for both sides.
The movie does a good job of making you wonder after the fact which oddities were happening due to Minnie, and which were the fault of Abraxas or Wriggles. We see Minnie on the monitor multiple times, once in the mirror on the table, and once behind jack backstage in a mirror. She's definitely present the entire time, whereas Wriggles likely isn't doing anything before Lilly walks out on stage.
I think if Minnie was the one causing the technical glitches like the lights flickering and audio feedback, it could be interpreted as either a threat or as a warning. She could be telling everyone to get out while they still can, knowing that something awful is coming. It could also be a threat to those in attendance, or it could be a product of Mr. Wriggles and not Minnie.
The demon and Minnie are certainly linked, likely because of Jack sacrificing her to the cult. This may be Minnie attempting to free herself by having Jack stab her.
I also just thought - could Minnie be the demon that is inside Lilly? They both "die" simultaneously as Jack stabs them. I don't think there's much to that theory but it does seem they both are "set free" at the same moment.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! Please consider registering your account, which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your post if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Registering is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see Why should I register my account?
